# Per game tagging and new users

Tags: discussion, tagging

Now that we're in public beta, you need 150 rep to create a new tag.

We recommend that any question that's specific to a particular game should have that game's name as a tag.

If you're a new user and you ask a question about a game that's never been mentioned before, then you can't create the tag for that game - @matiash had this problem [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/890/trivial-pursuit-rules-for-a-short-to-medium-length-game) with trivial pursuit.

Can I suggest that we have a tag for "Game that doesn't have a tag yet and I don't have enough rep to create one" so that 200+ users (500+ when we go live) can easily spot these questions and retag them.  Any suggestions of a good name for that tag?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to ditch this rule and allow moderators to see a list of all recent new tags? Then they can retag accordingly.

Comment: @Michiel - users with access to the moderators tools at 2k rep do have access to a list of all new tags.

Answer (score 6):

What about: request-game-tag or request-tag.

We could even add more request-* tags if there is need for them.

Comment: There's been suggestions in the past of letting users flag posts for things like "needs editing" or "should be closed", but they've never really taken off; a set of `request-*` tags (OMG meta tags!) for it seems the best way

Answer (score 0):

While I think adding `request-*` tags is a viable option for newer users, it seems to me like the newer users may not really know to look for a `request-*` type tag.

Best answer may be for a person with high enough rep to just add/re-tag it when they find it.

Comment: That would be the solution in the end. But then they can comment on the use of the request=* tag.